# extends MouseAdapter and implements ActionListener

Tags: java, event-handling, actionlistener

Why when we write an event handling we write

private class a extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener

why with a MouseAdapter extends and with ActionListener implements, is it matter if it become extends ActionListener implements MouseAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You can't write

```
extends ActionListener implements MouseAdapter
```

since `ActionListener` is a interface and `MouseAdapter` is not. A better question is why the author did not write

```
implements MouseListener, ActionListener
```

and the likely answer is:

`MouseAdapter` is an empty implementation of interface `MouseListener` which defines several event methods. Now if you want to implement only on event method, e.g. `mouseClicked`, then implementing `MouseListener` forces you to add empty implementations for all other mouse methods. Deriving from `MouseAdapter` allows you to only override specific methods, making your listener class smaller.

Now with Java 8 ability to define default methods, interfaces like `MouseListener` should really have empty default implementations, making `MouseAdapter` superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

ActionListener has a single method. MouseListener has many methods. So, you can implement MouseListener, but then you need to implement all its methods, even if you just want to handle a single event type (like mouseClicked, for example).

MouseAdapter is a class that implements MouseListener, and implements all its methods by doing... nothing. So extending MouseAdapter is handy: it allows overriding only the methods of interest. There would be no point in creating an ActionAdapter, since it would contain a single method, that you would always have to override to do something useful.

Note, though, that having a single class handle both mouse events and action events is a design smell. A listener should focus on a single task: handling a given event, from a given source.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a MouseAdapter and a ActionListener is that the a MouseAdapter is a abstract class and an ActionListener is an interface. In Java interfaces are implemented, and abstract classes are extended.

Abstract classes and interfaces can fulfil similar roles but have some key differences, I'd advice you to check out the documentation for both to find out more.

MouseAdapter
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html
ActionListener https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html